# Getting all prime numbers

Tags: c, loops, primes

Im trying to get all prime numbers from 1 to 10. My code is not working though, can anyone tell me why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i = 10;
    int n = 10;

    for(; i > 1; i-- ) {
        while(n > 1) {
            if((i % (n - 1)) == 0) {
                printf("%d is not a prime number", i);
                break;
                n--;
            }
        }
        n = 10;
        printf("%d is a prime number", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Getting a really large computation time and no output.

Comment: So you have `break;` BEFORE `n--;`? That could be a problem. I think you meant that increment to be after the `if` block.

Comment: A single pass stepping through the code in a debugger would have shown you the logic error in less time than it took you to type this site's URL into your browser's address bar. You should learn to use the debugger now; it's one of the most important tools in a programmers toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

We beginners should help each other.

Here is a demonstrative program I tried to use your approach as close as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i > 1; i-- ) 
    {
        int n = i - 1;
        while ( n > 1 && i % n != 0 ) n--; 

        if ( n == 1 )
        {
            printf("%d is a prime number\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 is not a prime number
9 is not a prime number
8 is not a prime number
7 is a prime number
6 is not a prime number
5 is a prime number
4 is not a prime number
3 is a prime number
2 is a prime number
```

Setting the constant `N` with any arbitrary positive value you can get all prime numbers before and including `N`.

As for your program then you should place the first statement with `printf` outside the inner loop. Also this statement  `n--;` has to follow the if statement. And when `i` is equal to 2 and `n` is also equal to 2 then you will get that 2 is not a prime number because this expression `i % (n - 1)) == 0` yields true.

You could write a separate function that checks whether a given number is prime.
Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime( unsigned int n )
{
    int prime = ( n == 2 ) || ( n != 1 && n % 2 );

    for ( unsigned i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        printf( "\nPrime numbers up to %u:", n );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( is_prime( i + 1 ) ) printf( " %u", i + 1 );
        }

        printf( "\n\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As @Zaid pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42494228/14660), the infinite loop is being caused by the `n--` being inside the `if` statement. The `if` condition will eventually fail, so it's eventually going to get stuck in an infinite loop.

It turns out the inner while loop is another for loop.

```
for( n = 10; n > 1; n-- )
```

This kind of mistake is why for loops are used, it clearly spells out the initialization, termination condition, and incrementing.

This doesn't make the code work, but it's not infinite.

---

What you're basically trying to do is for each number, try dividing it by every number lower than itself.

```
for( i = 10; i > 1; i-- ) {  // every number from 10 to 2
    for( n = i-1; n > 1; n-- ) { // every number lower than i to 2.
        if( i % n == 0 ) {
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // If n reached 1, it made it through the sieve.
    if( n <= 1 ) {
        printf("%d is a prime number\n", i);
    }
}
```

Note that by starting n at i - 1 there's no need to remember to compare i against n - 1. That simplifies the code, and it's one less potential bug.

---

There's several ways to optimize this. We can observe a few things:

An integer never is never evenly divisible when n > i/2. So 10 is never going to be divisible by 9, 8, 7, or 6. That means we can start counting n at i/2 and save a bunch of checks. Since this is integer division, i/2 will always round down, there's no need to do that ourselves.

The smaller a prime divisor is the more likely it is to be a divisor. Half the numbers are divisible by 2, 1/3 are divisible by 3, 1/5 by 5... so it's faster to start from the bottom and increment n.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    int divisor;

    // From 10 to 2.
    for( num = 10; num > 1; num-- ) {
        // From 2 to num/2, no need to go further.
        for( divisor = 2; divisor <= num/2; divisor++ ) {
            if( num % divisor == 0 ) {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we got past num/2 it's prime
        if( divisor > num/2 ) {
            printf("%d is a prime number\n", num);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We can this a step further and observe that even numbers are never prime. This means even numbers are also never prime divisors. If we start n on an odd number, we can count up by 2 halving the number of checks again. If we skipped even numbers entirely, this is easy.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    int divisor;

    // Count down from 11 by 2s.
    for( num = 11; num > 1; num -= 2 ) {
        // From 3 to num/2. No need to check 2, we skipped even numbers.
        for( divisor = 3; divisor <= num/2; divisor += 2 ) {
            if( num % divisor == 0 ) {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Same end condition as before.
        if( divisor > num/2 ) {
            printf("%d is a prime number\n", num);
        }
    }

    // Special case for 2.
    printf("2 is a prime number\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want all numbers, you can put a special case inside the main loop to check if it's even. Again, 2 is special cased so we don't have to continually check that num != 2 inside the loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    int divisor;

    // Count down from 10 to 3, 2 is special cased.
    for( num = 10; num > 2; num-- ) {
        // Special case for even numbers so we can still do the
        // for loop by 2s.
        if( num % 2 == 0 ) {
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);
            continue;
        }

        // 3 to num/2, odd numbers only.
        for( divisor = 3; divisor <= num/2; divisor += 2 ) {
            if( num % divisor == 0 ) {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);
                break;
            }
        }

        if( divisor > num/2 ) {
            printf("%d is a prime number\n", num);
        }
    }

    // Again, special case for 2 to reduce code operations inside the loop
    printf("2 is a prime number\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop in entering in infinite loop because you are decrementing `n` inside `if` statement block .

Put `n--` after the closing braces of `if` block inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

See fix below.
Major problems:

1. The reason your program doesn't end is pinned to the if sentence inside the first while loop - consider `i = 10` and `n-1 = 9`. In this case, the if sentence will resolve to `false` and the program will endlessly loop because `n--` never occurs.
2. Even if your program did conclude, it will always print `%d is not a prime number` AND `%d is a prime number` for all non-prime numbers (why?)
3. Since your modulo is around `n-1`, and `n` decrements to 2, every number you test will be a non-prime (you're testing for `i%1`)
4. Other than that - you're all good (;

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>

   int main(void) {
       int i;
       int n;

       for(i = 10; i > 1; i-- ) {
           n = i;
           while( n > 2 ) {
               if( ( i % ( n-1 ) ) == 0 ) {
                   printf( "%d is not a prime number\n", i );
                   break;
               }
               n--;
           }
           if (n == 2)
               printf( "%d is a prime number\n" , i );
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: wouldnt this always print "is a prime number" when n = 2? EDIT: Followed your code more closely, I was wrong

Comment: Yeah it's funny how confusing this is... Had to compile and run to get it right (;

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 10;
    for(; i > 1; i-- ) {
        int n = 10;
        int flag = 0;
        while(n > 2) {
            if((i % (n - 1)) == 0) {
                flag = 1; 
                printf("%d is not a prime number", i);
                break;
            }
            n--;
        }
        if(flag == 0) { 
            printf("%d is a prime number", i);
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is a problem because you are decremeting after you break, this makes no sense

**EDIT: I just realized this will always print "is a prime number", you need to set up a flag to tell you if it is a prime number or not.**

Comment: Your code doesn't detect prime numbers. You should alter the while condition to `n>2` because op uses `n-1` for comparison, leading to `i % 1 == 0` for any i

Comment: @IshayPeled Yup you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am not answering your homework questions for you but...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int i = 10;
int n = 10;

for(i=10; i>1; i--)  {
    n=i;                       
    while( n > 1 ) {
        /* You also need to check to make sure that you aren't checking for 1 here. */
        if( ( i % ( n-1 ) ) == 0 && (n-1 !=1)) {
            printf("\n\n %d is not a prime number",i);
            break;
        }
        n--; /* This is culprit number one, your control operator is never being hit because it is after the break statement */
        if (n==1){
           /* n==1 means This should never be called unless the entire loop has proven every other number has been checked */
           printf( "\n\n %d is a prime number" , i );
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simple and solid way to do this is the following way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,a;
    for(i=2;i<=10;i++){
        for(a=2;a<i;a++)
             if(a%i==0)
                 break;
        if(a==i)
             printf("%d is a prime number",i);
     }
    return 0;
}
```